# mysqli query to count multiple specific words in each db record

Tags: sql, mysqli, count, sum, case

I require some help with counting multiple specific words within a records title field.

so here is my query

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN `title` LIKE '%fish%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count1,
FROM tbl_recipes
GROUP BY recipeID
```

which is working but if i want to count multiple words im not sure i how to achieve this.

I've tried something like this

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN title LIKE '%fish%' OR WHEN title LIKE '%soup%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count1,
FROM tbl_recipes
GROUP BY recipeID
```

But this throws up an exception, does anyone know the correct way to count multiple instances of specific words in a database field.

there could be upto 6 words that need counting, and i need them all to be counted as the same count not seperatly :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For individual counts you have to try somthing like this:-

```
SELECT
SUM(CASE WHEN title LIKE '%fish%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count1,
SUM(CASE WHEN title LIKE '%soup%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count2,
SUM(CASE WHEN title LIKE '%fish%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count1 +
SUM(CASE WHEN title LIKE '%soup%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count2 AS TOTAL
FROM tbl_recipes
GROUP BY recipeID
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, how would i add up the total sum for each record ie count1 +count2 etc? i've tried using Sum(count1)+SUM(count2)as total_matches in my query but it says unknown column count1. so can i not use these columns? many thanks

Comment: No you cant't use them like this. For total you can see edit portion